# What happened to Ion hypermedia type?

Tags: json, http, media-type

Les Hazlewood submitted the Ion spec to the IETF for a JSON-based hypermedia type for REST APIs. But, it seems to have been [dead since 2018.](https://github.com/ionwg/ion-doc)

What happened to it? Did something else replace it?

Comment: Did you find an answer? That spec seemed extremely promising

Comment: No. It's a shame it never went anywhere, it looked much better than some of the popular standards in use now.

Comment: I totally agree. I loved that spec when I first read it. Do someone knows about something equivalent and valid today?